# I have two ids for a project it's a tribute page the two ids are needed to pass but when i go to center the title it doesn't center

Tags: html, css

I tried to center the title but it doesn't center i used css grid on images but shouldn't that not affect the id

this has not worked and I can't figure out why

```css
#main{

    text-align: center;

  }
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <h1 id="title"> Dr.Norman Borlaug</h1>
</div>
```

but when I run it it shows the text should be centered but when i refresh the page on chrome it doesn't move to the center.

```html
<div id="main">
  <h1 id="title"> Dr.Norman Borlaug</h1>
</div>

<div id="img-div">
<div class="row">
  <img src="img/normanwithpeople.png" alt="Norman Borlaug having a conversion with colleuges">
  <img src="img/norman-borlaug.png" alt="Norman Borlaug in a field smiling" id ="image">
  <p id="img-caption"></p>
    </div>
     <div class="column">
    
    <img src="img/normanatconference.png" alt="Norman Borlaug at a confrence">
     <img src="img/normanwithjimmy.png" alt="Norman_Borlaug with  former President Jimmy Carter">
    
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="img/norman.png" alt="Norman Borlaug and his wife">
    <img src="img/normangetsaward.png" alt="Norman Borlaug receives an award from president George W Bush">
  </div>

     <div class="column">
      <img src="img/normanwithgranddaughter.png" alt="Norman Borlaug with his granddaughter who is carrying his great grandchild">
      <img src="img/normaninmexico.jpg"  alt=" A painting of Norman Borlaug in a field in Mexico">



  </div>
```

this the code before where the title is located but the rest is images i don't know how this helps.

Comment: Make sure the div is of full width first

Comment: It will be better if you show more code

Comment: The request for more code was because the code you've provided doesn't reproduce your issue. Your new added code doesn't reproduce it either; if I add the CSS from your first snippet your title is centered in Chrome. Your question is still missing whatever it is that is causing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't include adequate code, I'm unable to guess what your issue is. Make sure you put CSS inside a `<style>` HTML tag, or inside a stylesheet, neither of which are visible inside your included code.

This seemed to work for me:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
        #main{text-align: center;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
        <h1 id="title"> Dr.Norman Borlaug</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="img-div">
        <div class="row">
        <img src="img/normanwithpeople.png" alt="Norman Borlaug having a conversion with colleuges">
        <img src="img/norman-borlaug.png" alt="Norman Borlaug in a field smiling" id ="image">
        <p id="img-caption"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="column">
            
            <img src="img/normanatconference.png" alt="Norman Borlaug at a confrence">
            <img src="img/normanwithjimmy.png" alt="Norman_Borlaug with  former President Jimmy Carter">
            
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <img src="img/norman.png" alt="Norman Borlaug and his wife">
            <img src="img/normangetsaward.png" alt="Norman Borlaug receives an award from president George W Bush">
        </div>

            <div class="column">
            <img src="img/normanwithgranddaughter.png" alt="Norman Borlaug with his granddaughter who is carrying his great grandchild">
            <img src="img/normaninmexico.jpg"  alt=" A painting of Norman Borlaug in a field in Mexico">
    </body>
    </div>
</html>
```